# openxml with asynchron structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am working with MS SQL Server 2012.

I am trying to use the function openxml with the following statement / xml data:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SET @SQL = '<master>
  <List>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Peter</DisplayFieldName>
      <Value>
        <string>Yes</string>
      </Value>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Tom</DisplayFieldName>
      <Value>
        <string>No</string>
      </Value> 
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Numerics</DisplayFieldName>     
      <Value>
        <string>50          </string>
        <string>100          </string>
        <string>150          </string>
        <string>200          </string> 
      </Value>
    </Col>
  </List>
</master>'


SELECT @XML = CONVERT(XML,@SQL)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/master/List/Col/Value',3)  
WITH 
(
string [varchar](max)
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

The result is this:

```
  string
1 Yes
2 No
3 50
```

I understand why this happens, but actually I would like to display just all numerical values (50,100,150,200) or at least all values in the  field (Yes, No, 50, 100, 150, 200) which also would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more (There are some rare exceptions...)

You should rather use the XML-methods like `.value()`,`.nodes()`,`.query()` and `.exist()`.

Give this a try: It is fully inlined (ad-hoc), easier to read and maintain -  and much faster:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SET @XML = '<master>
  <List>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Peter</DisplayFieldName>
      <Value>
        <string>Yes</string>
      </Value>
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Tom</DisplayFieldName>
      <Value>
        <string>No</string>
      </Value> 
    </Col>
    <Col>
      <DisplayFieldName>Numerics</DisplayFieldName>     
      <Value>
        <string>50          </string>
        <string>100          </string>
        <string>150          </string>
        <string>200          </string> 
      </Value>
    </Col>
  </List>
</master>';

SELECT C.value('DisplayFieldName[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DisplayFieldName
      ,V.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS string

FROM @XML.nodes('/master/List/Col') AS A(C)
CROSS APPLY C.nodes('Value/string') AS B(V);
```

The result

```
DisplayFieldName    string
----------------------------
Peter               Yes
Tom                 No
Numerics            50          
Numerics            100          
Numerics            150          
Numerics            200
```

### UPDATE

If you need the numerics only, you could append the same XQuery-filter to the `.nodes()` XPath, as pointed by Alex: `/master/List/Col[DisplayFieldName="Numerics"]`

Answer (score 1):

Make xpath deeper. Filter data. Something like this.

```
SELECT text string
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/master/List/Col[DisplayFieldName="Numerics"]/Value/string',3)  
--WITH 
--(
--string [varchar](max)
--)
where text is not null
```

### update

You can also use native xml methods.

```
select t.v.value('.','varchar(100)') x
from @xml.nodes('master/List/Col[DisplayFieldName="Numerics"]/Value/string') t(v)
```

In my experience `openxml` works faster with large texts.

Answer (score 1):

You can give this a try, might return more than what you are expecting:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/master/List/Col/Value/*', 3) 
WITH 
(
string [varchar](max) '.'
)
```

Comment: works if you want to display all values (not only numerics), simply and nice